# Django bulk create with self reference foreign key

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a question about Django objects creation using `bulk_create()`

Here is a part of my model :

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent_group = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

And then I want to create like this :

```py
df_records = df.to_dict('records')
model_instances = [Group(
    uid = record["uid"],
    label = record["label"],
    group_parent = Group(uid=record["parent_uid"]),
    ) for record in df_records]
Group.objects.bulk_create(model_instances)
```

Is it possible to self-reference parents in a bulk create (of course the parent is in the same bulk)?
Or do I have to set parent to null and iterate throughout all objects to find the parent Django object id?

Comment: If `uid` is a primary key, yes. But here it is apparently not a primary key.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Willem,

I post here my working code :

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    parent_group = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

and the bulk_create

```py
df_records = df.to_dict('records')
model_instances = [Group(
    uid = record["uid"],
    label = record["label"],
    group_parent_id = record["parent_uid"],
    ) for record in df_records]
Group.objects.bulk_create(model_instances)
```